# Handling Http status code 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: http-status-code-302

It can be said that when I receive a status code 302 and in the response a Location header with another URL, it means that I should make another request in this other URL?

Sending Http POST request to https://customer-test.com/order/checkout?id=491

Response headers

```
Status code HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
Response headers:
Header name: Content-Type, header value: text/html; charset=utf-8
Header name: Transfer-Encoding, header value: chunked
Header name: Status, header value: 302 Found
Header name: Cache-Control, header value: no-cache
Header name: Referrer-Policy, header value: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Header name: X-Robots-Tag, header value: none
Header name: X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies, header value: none
Header name: X-XSS-Protection, header value: 1; mode=block
Header name: X-Request-Id, header value: af014ce9-3e67-4aa7-9dc3-cfaffe2b301a
Header name: Location, header value: https://another.url.com/sessions/new
Header name: X-Download-Options, header value: noopen
Header name: X-Runtime, header value: 0.122752
Header name: X-Frame-Options, header value: SAMEORIGIN
Header name: X-Content-Type-Options, header value: nosniff
Header name: Date, header value: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 16:35:16 GMT
Header name: Set-Cookie, header value: _customer_session=59939fa7ad350971e4799114897sdf5; path=/; expires=Wed, 21 Jul 2021 16:35:16 -0000; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Header name: Strict-Transport-Security, header value: max-age=16070400
Header name: Front-End-Https, header value: onenter code here
```

Afterwards, I tried to get the location URL and submit another HTTP POST, but I get a 400 status code.

Disparando POST request para https://sanofi-test.coupahost.com/sessions/new
Sending Http POST request para https://customer-test.com/sessions/new

```
Status code HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Response headers:
Header name: Content-Type, header value: text/html
Header name: Transfer-Encoding, header value: chunked
Header name: Status, header value: 400 Bad Request
Header name: Cache-Control, header value: no-cache
Header name: Referrer-Policy, header value: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Header name: X-Robots-Tag, header value: none
Header name: X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies, header value: none
Header name: X-XSS-Protection, header value: 1; mode=block
Header name: X-Request-Id, header value: 1c8c4c6b-bd94-4b98-b83e-974569276e4d
Header name: X-Download-Options, header value: noopen
Header name: X-Runtime, header value: 0.102914
Header name: X-Frame-Options, header value: SAMEORIGIN
Header name: X-Content-Type-Options, header value: nosniff
Header name: Date, header value: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 16:35:17 GMT
```

Sorry, I'm new and I don't understand the situation.

Comment: You were correct to send a new request to the location you got from that header. You then got a 400 error, but that does not mean you followed the redirect incorrectly. It just means your second request, to the correct URL, was not well-formed as far as the server is concerned. To try to know why the server thinks so, we would have to know what the spec is for that particular URL/endpoint; sometimes, the server will tell you more about this in the response body, sometimes you have to consult the remote service's documentation. Anyway, it does not seem related to the redirect.

Comment: Hello @Noah thanks for help me!! I will talk to the company that is exposing the API.